# NSDocument Saving audio And Vidoes Files

Tags: iphone, ios, media, nsdocument, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an ios App That has Download Feature for Audio and Video Files The Question Is Where Should I Download These Files And How ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

create file like this

```
NSString *filePath = NSTemporaryDirectory();

filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.mp3"];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

write your audiostream description like this

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription des;
des.mSampleRate = 44000;
des.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
des.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
des.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
des.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
des.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
```

create audio file like this

```
AudioFileID audioFile;
audioErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, 
                                 kAudioFileWAVEType,   
                                  &des,
                                  kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                  &audioFile);
```

use  `AudioFileWriteBytes(audioFile)`method to write it